# Publishing a web service in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I want to publish a Web Service written in Visual Studio 2010 using WCF Service Application. But while publishing I'm getting the floowing error

Web deployment task failed. (`A value for the 'setAclUser' setting must be specified when the 'setAcl' provider is used with a physical path.`)     0   0

In Publish window in *site/application*, I've written *C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CustomerService*

Can anyone tell what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACL stand for Access Control list. probably the webservice uses an other account which can't acces de user folder. Try publishing your webservice outside your user profile and give it the proper access.